# Play framework template cannot escape URL

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, playframework-2.0, template-engine

I have this Play template, dynamicLink.scala.html...

```
@( urlWithQuotes: Html, id: Html, toClick: Html )

@uniqueId_With_Quotes() = {
    Html("\"" + (@id) + "_" + scala.util.Random.nextInt.toString + "\"")
}

@defining(uniqueId_With_Quotes()) { uniqueID =>
    <a id=@uniqueID class="dynamicLink" href=@urlWithQuotes> @toClick </a>

    <script><!--Do stuff with dynamic link using jQuery--></script>
}
```

It generates a special link with some Javascript. I render this link like so...

```
@dynamicLink(
    Html("@{routes.Controller.action()}"),
    Html("MyID"),
    Html("Click Me")
)
```

When I render it, I get...

```
<a id=
Html("\"" + (MyID) + "_" + scala.util.Random.nextInt.toString + "\"")
class="dynamicLink" href=@{routes.Controler.action()}> Click Me </a>
```

This is not what I want to render. I want to render this...

```
<a id="MyID_31734697" class="dynamicLink" href="/path/to/controller/action"> Click Me </a>
```

How do I make this HTML escape correctly?

*** Take #2 - replacing Html params with String ***

```
@(urlWithQuotes: String, id: String, toClickOn: String)

@uniqueId_With_Quotes() = {
    Html("\"" + (@id) + "_" + scala.util.Random.nextInt.toString + "\"")
}

@defining(uniqueId_With_Quotes) { uniqueID =>
    <a id=@uniqueID class="dynamicLink" href=@urlWithQuotes> @toClickOn </a>
    ...
}
```

With...

```
@dynamicLink2(
"@{routes.Controller.action()}",
"MyID",
"Click Me"
)
```

Renders...

```
    <a id=
    Html("\"" + (MyID) + "_" + scala.util.Random.nextInt.toString + "\"")
 class="dynamicLink" href=@{routes.Controller.action()}> Click Me </a>
    <script>
        ...
    </script>
```

*** Changing Html to String didn't work ***

*** Note that " *@uniqueId_With_Quotes()* " expands into " *Html("\"" + (MyID) + "_" + scala.util.Random.nextInt.toString + "\"")* ". I want it to actually execute string concatenation. ***

Also, this should be obvious, but I want each link and the accompanying jquery to be rendered with an ID that is unique to that link and I don't want the controller to have to worry about assigning these unique id's. My way of doing that is by appending a random number to each id (although it might just be better for the view to have a count). I need to have this stateful behavior in the view because I need "dynamicLink" to be totally transparent to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use the variables as String types?

```
@( urlWithQuotes: String, id: String, toClick: String )
```

Comment: Changing Html to String didn't work. Also, I don't know when I should use Html and when I should use String (outside of user forms, which should always use String just to protect again injection)

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. You have to pass a Call object.

```
    @dynamicLink(
    ({routes.Controller.action()}),
    "MyID",
    "Click Me"
    )
```

Pass those parameters into...

```
@(urlNoQuotes: Call, id: String = "", toClickOn: String = "")

@uniqueId_With_Quotes() = @{
    Html("\"" + (id) + "_" + scala.util.Random.nextInt.toString + "\"")
}

@url() = @{
    Html("\"" + urlNoQuotes + "\"")
}

@defining( url() ) { processedURL =>
    @defining(uniqueId_With_Quotes()) { uniqueID =>
    ... 
    }
}
```

^ Now it works.